# Map dynamically all types of functions in object

Tags: typescript

How to extract all function return types

```
const t = {
    fn1: a => ({test1: 1}),
    fn2: b => ({test2: 1}),
    fn3: c => ({test3: 1}),
}

let a: ReturnType<typeof t["fn1"]> | ReturnType<typeof t["fn2"]> | ReturnType<typeof t["fn3"]>;
//or
let b: ReturnType<typeof t["fn1"] |  typeof t["fn2"] | typeof t["fn3"]>;
```

Is it possible to map dynamically all types of `fn1`, `fn2`... into a one type?  So get rid of that `ReturnType<typeof t["fn1"]> | ReturnType<typeof t["fn2"]>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically map it by simply using the `keyof typeof t` to access all possible keys of `t`, i.e.:

```
let a: ReturnType<typeof t[keyof typeof t]>;
```

This will cause the type to be inferred as:

```
let a: {
    test1: number;
} | {
    test2: number;
} | {
    test3: number;
}
```

See [proof-of-concept on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBLC8MDeAoG6YDMwEYBcMAFAJQzwB8RSUAptPjDgL7EA0aG2ATASWZYWp0oPRi3YYsYAMy9SFKrWiyxbFExQoANjVgBDAgCVdAVwBOYACoBPAA40APFDs0QmOAG0A1jWtu4Lv5QALrkANxAA) (I have removed the unused parameters `a`, `b` and `c` for demo purposes).